# Bluetooth Server Closed

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to try creating again `bluetooth` connection on Fragment (because I want to send message, If I don't creating again getting return null object) And my problem is : Working on the fragment than my server socket closed.

This is my log:

```
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: Closed Socket.
                           run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
                           connected: Starting.
                           ConnectedThread: Starting.
E/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Error reading Input Stream. socket closed
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
W/SplitWindow: update focus... 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/SplitWindow: update focus... 
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Writing to outputstream: Name
E/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Error writing to output stream. socket closed
```

And this is connection code:

```
package com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context mContext;
    private  BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread(){
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try{
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName,MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try{
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if(socket == null){
                connected(socket,mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                if(!mmSocket.isConnected())
                {
                    mmSocket.connect();
                    connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
                }

                //mmSocket.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    if(mmSocket!=null) {
                        mmSocket.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                    }
                    //  createBluetoothSocket(mmDevice);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            }

            connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
            try {
                final Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                Log.d(TAG, "Creating bluetooth socket");

                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
            }
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_INSECURE);
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public synchronized  void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth" ,"Please Wait...",true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    /**
     Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the BTConnection, Sending the data, and
     receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
     **/
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try{
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();

            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                tmpOut=mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");

                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage", incomingMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                mmOutStream.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        if(mConnectedThread==null){

        }
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }
    public void SocketClose(){
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I think my problem is here, socket was closed but it has to start again:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
        mmDevice = device;
        deviceUUID = uuid;
    }

    public void run(){
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                    +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
        }

        mmSocket = tmp;

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

        try {
            if(!mmSocket.isConnected())
            {
                mmSocket.connect();
                connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
            }

            //mmSocket.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
             if(mmSocket!=null) {
                 mmSocket.close();
                 Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
             }

                //  createBluetoothSocket(mmDevice);


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
        }
        connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
    }
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Send Message starting just only on the MainActivty. So if you try on the fragment or another activity you are failed.

You have to write method that is send message on Main activity.And the method has to call on the fragment and send message choose on the fragment bu data has to send on the main activty.